# How to use a static class method as a filter for Kohana's Validation Library?

Tags: php, validation, kohana

Kohana's Validation library has a pre_filter() method which lets you apply any PHP function to fields to be validated, as trim(), etc.
I tried to use a static method as a filter, but won't work:
`$validation->pre_filter( 'field_name', 'class::method' )`

What that does is create two filters, one with `class` and antoher one with `method`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback is one of PHP's [pseudo-types](https://www.php.net/callback).  It will let you pass a

1. function
2. method of an instantiated object
3. static method/class method

to a PHP function/method that's expecting a callback, and the PHP function/method will know what to do with it.

From the manual

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs such as: array(), echo(), empty(), eval(), exit(), isset(), list(), print() or unset().
>
> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.
>
> Static class methods can also be passed without instantiating an object of that class by passing the class name instead of an object at index 0.

So, to use a static method in place of a callback string, you'd use

```
array('className','methodName');
```

If Kohana is using standard PHP callbacks, this should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks to both answers, they look like correct PHP, however I suspect Kohana's Validation lib is doing some naughty eval() or something, because it doesn't work with this. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use a static method call back the callback needs to be an array.. for example:

`array('MyCoolClassName', 'methodName');`

so assuming its using call_user_func then your method call should be:

`$validation->pre_filter( 'field_name', array('MyCoolClassName', 'methodName'));`

or if you need to use an object instance:

`$validation->pre_filter( 'field_name', array($objectInstance, 'methodName'));`